# New kernel paramter "crashkernel" appeared in /etc/default/grub after update

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

Yesterday there was an update of several GRUB related packages, among those were:

- `grub-common:amd64` (`2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15`)
- `grub2-common:amd64` (`2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15`)
- `grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64` (`2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15`)
- `grub-efi-amd64:amd64` (`2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15`)
- `grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64` (`1.66.15+2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.15`)

During the installation I was prompted whether to keep my old `/etc/default/grub` or install the updated one. On examining the differences, the only notable change (apart from resetting some timeouts and the default entry, etc.) was the addition of the `crashkernel` parameter as seen below:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to "crashkernel=384M-2G:128M,2G-:256M"
```

I declined the change for now to keep my customizations, but I wonder what this parameter it wanted to add would mean and if I should add it again or leave it be. What is it good for and do I need it or not?

Comment: I found this on RedHat https://access.redhat.com/solutions/59432

Comment: The crashkernel stuff seems to keep coming and going from the default grub stuff. You might find that even when it is not included in grub, the kernel command line still ends up with it. do `cat /proc/cmdline` to see. I get `BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-rc3-rjwlow root=UUID=bcbc624b-892b-46ca-9e9e-102daf644170 ro ipv6.disable=1 consoleblank=300 crashkernel=384M-2G:128M,2G-:256M` even though I do not have any crashkernel stuff in grub (the other stuff, I do specify).